# Could the electron count as a force-carrying particle?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons, weak-interaction

Pretty straight-forward this one. If we're going to get a bit more nit-picky about this relatively straight-forward question I'd like to first of all point out that yes, I have considered that electrical charges themselves may well, in fact, be 'mediated' by the W and Z vector bosons. However, it might even be conceivable that this is leading to further questions as to how a 'boson' is defined in terms other than it's spin statistics and whether or not more than one particle can play a role in the transmission of certain forces like, I don't know, gravity for example.

Comment: You may certainly have one-electron exchange Feynman diagrams, with energy and momentum transfer. What do you choose to define as "force"? Only gravitons mediate gravity.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ok, I understand that, however what I'm suggesting is that there is some potentially chameleon-like properties of the electron of which we're currently unaware. Does this clarify my statement? I.e. the 'graviton' may as well be the place-holder name for whatever particle turns out to be mediating gravity; I think the electron has certain convenient properties that make it a good candidate.

Comment: I see... ambition grows on what it feeds on.

Comment: Interesting. What does it feed on?

Comment: What properties can an electron have for mediating gravity considering it doesnt even have enough spin states and also interacts electromagnetically/weakly. Not to mention it is massive and couldn't propagate at the speed of light (of which many constraints were placed with the recent LIGO gravitational wave detection experiments)

Comment: They seem to be able to tunnel instantaneously. As for spin states I was only aware of two possible spin states for any and all SM particles, either up or down. As for interacting electromagnetically/weakly, well I thought that this was sort of the point of unification theories, that these forces ought to tie in together in some fundamental way; it's not that it doesn't interact via the EM or electroweak interaction, it's that gravity may be shown to be some sort of secondary effect of this force. All this is speculative, sort of.